# Zoom function for add in in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am completely new at gis but I have to make an add in to work with arcmap to make it zoom to a place I want it to go. (I use a textfield in a php website to tell where to go in arcmap) Is there a zoom function I can use in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what input data you have (coordinates, street address, city name etc), you might try different approaches.

1. Develop a [.NET/Java based ArcMap add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS/01w200000002000000/) or [Python Add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000025000000) where a user will enter a certain place (in the form you define beforehand), and the current map extent will be updated.
2. If you are fine doing this in several steps without custom programming - consider using [ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_ModelBuilder/002w00000001000000/) or writing a [Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_Python/002z00000001000000/) script tool to let user enter coordinates/place name and then implement a logic that will [geocode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_geocoding/002500000001000000/) the address or put a pin on the map. Then the user will use a built-in tool for zooming to this object.
3. If it is coordinates, then use might just use the [Go to XY tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000043r000000).

Comment: I think I have to use the XY tool but it has to automatically zoom to the x and y coordinates when I press a button in my php.

Comment: I don't really follow you on what you mean by "press a button in my php". You could maybe edit your question or add a comment with some information? There is no way to make ArcMap do something when you are in some website (it is a desktop application). If you want something to happen in your ArcMap session while you interact with a web site, you would need to start using some client-server logic, which is really a different story.

Comment: I mean the webbrowser toolbox tool in C#, i want it arcmap to react to the webbrowser toolbox tool